# Possible to merge two databases?

Tags: database

We have a production and dev database. The dev database is typically only used to change core features, channel setup, add-ons, etc. Never content.

We’re in a situation where we need to pull some posts for a channel down from the production version, but I’m not sure if it’s possible.

Is there a way to do this manually and safely, or an add-on that can help take care of it?

Comment: you've hit the holy grail